# Should a question be closed as a duplicate of a question which only has limited interest?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I asked a question which was similar to one posed a while back. That question was closed because it was deemed to be of only limited interest.

I noted that I was aware of the original.

Who decides if a question is of limited interest? Where is the logic in closing a question because it is a duplicate when the duplicate was closed because it is of limited interest?

Comment: This may be helpful, @paul: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: On Meta, downvotes are an indication of disagreement, not a reflection on the quality of your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Who decides if a question is of limited interest?

It's the community who decides which questions are acceptable for its Stack Exchange site, and it is always the community who decide when a question has been wrongly closed.

Too localized questions generally have more than one issue:

- The OP doesn't explain what s/he tried ("I thought using [word], but I when I read the phrase to my colleague, she didn't understand what I meant.")
- The OP sets arbitrary limits on what s/he consider acceptable
- The OP doesn't describe exactly which word is looking for, with the result that at every answer s/he adds a comment explaining s/he cannot use the suggested word
- There are few users who would look for a word that respects the same criteria used from the OP

> Where is the logic in closing a question because it is a duplicate when the duplicate was closed because it is of limited interest?

Every question that is duplicate of another question is closed as duplicate, even if the other question has been already closed. Eventually, it is the first closed question that gets re-opened, if it was wrongly closed.
The fact another user asked a very similar question (so similar that has been closed as duplicate) doesn't mean the first question was not too localized. Even if 4 users would ask the same question, the question is still too localized.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to English.SE. I'll do my best to explain.

You are welcome to express disagreement about whether a question is too localized, but the appropriate way is to cast an upvote. If you have the necessary reputation you can also vote to reopen.

Knowingly creating a duplicate is frowned on. SE editors collect questions and their answers on one page to make them easy to use. Duplicates become pointers to the original. When you created your duplicate, all you accomplished was to waste several peoples’ time closing and linking it. (Considering that the same people also have the necessary reputation to vote to reopen the original question, and hence are people you might have wanted to influence, perhaps that was not the best move.)

To learn more about who decides what around here and how much reputation they need to earn the privilege, see [Privileges](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges).

When a question says “closed as too localized”, that doesn’t mean every closevoter voted that way. That’s just the majority reason. There are often multiple problems with a question that justify taking it offline. For example the original also showed no evidence of research effort.

Your argument seems to be that you and one other person asked a similar question, therefore the question is of broad interest to EL&U users. Your argument does not convince me of its unstated premise that two people are sufficient to prove the question to be of broad interest. To the contrary: five experienced editors thought the question needed to be taken offline, and only two people upvoted the original question. Those facts carry greater weight with me.

Comment: OTOH, if yet another person asks the same question where prior instances were closed as "too localized", one should definitely rethink their decision of closing it as "too localized" - apparently the answer is useful to much wider audience than originally thought.'